# How to run XPI files without Firefox?

Tags: windows, firefox-extensions, sqlite

Is it possible to run [SQLite Manager](http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-manager/), or other XPI, outside Firefox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the [XULRunner](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/xulrunner) project which aims to do this, but from my experience it's a pretty big pain in the butt to set up (I tried within the last month or so) and I never got it working myself.

Comment: I did, but that was in a commercial context. You'd better ask on StackOverflow.com if you _really_ want this. Besides, XULRunner is essentially the same as FireFox, so there is little benefit. In hindsight we too should have just used FF.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there appears to be an alternative version that works outside the browser. For Mac and Windows. You can find it [here](http://www.sqlabs.net/sqlitemanager.php).

> SQLiteManager is a powerful database
>   manager for sqlite databases, it
>   combines an incredible easy to use
>   interface with blazing speed and
>   advanced features

XPI files themselves are:

> Cross-Platform Installer Module (XPI)
>   is a ZIP file used to install
>   packages, utilizing the XPInstall
>   technology. XPI modules (so called
>   "Bundles") are employed to install a
>   wide variety of software, including
>   Plugins, Extensions, Themes, and
>   Thunderbird dictionaries

(From the [Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPI))

This is specific to the Gecko engine (used with many Mozilla Products) and thus, can only be handled it by for installation. They CAN be unpacked up 7z or some other archiving tools, but cannot be run outside of the Gecko engine.

Comment: That's not the same product.